# How to unit test class that uses data model with child entities in Asp.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, moq

In my web store app I have a "Cart" class that can add, remove, and compute total value of items. The data model is the folowing: 1 Item contains 1 Product and 1 Shipping. Product has Price field and Shipping has Cost field.  Here is the Cart class code:

```
public class CartLine
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Cart
{
    private List<CartLine> lineCollection = new List<CartLine>();

    // methods: 
    // Add(Item item, int quantity) 
    // Remove(Item item)

    public decimal ComputeTotalProductValue()
    {
        return lineCollection.Sum(l => l.Item.Product.Price*l.Quantity);
    }

    // methods with the same principle: 
    // ComputeTotalShippingValue()
    // ComputeOveralValue()
}
```

And here is my unit test (that of course doesn't work):

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Can_Compute_Total_Values()
    {
        // Arrange 
        var itemMock = new Mock<IItemsRepository>();
        itemMock.Setup(i => i.GetItems()).Returns(new[]
            {
                new Item { ItemId = 1, ProductId = 1, ShippingId = 1 },
                new Item { ItemId = 2, ProductId = 2, ShippingId = 2 }
            });

        var productMock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
        productMock.Setup(p => p.GetProducts()).Returns(new[]
            {
                new Product { ProductId = 1, Price = 10 },
                new Product { ProductId = 2, Price = 20 }
            });

        var shippingMock = new Mock<IShippingRepository>();
        shippingMock.Setup(s => s.GetShippings()).Returns(new[]
            {
                new Shipping { ShippingId = 1, Cost = 2 },
                new Shipping { ShippingId = 2, Cost = 5 }
            });

        var item1 = itemMock.Object.GetItems().ToArray()[0];
        var item2 = itemMock.Object.GetItems().ToArray()[1];    

        var target = new Cart();

        //Act
        target.Add(item1, 2);
        target.Add(item2, 4);

        decimal totalProduct = target.ComputeTotalProductValue();
        decimal totalShipping = target.ComputeTotalShippingValue();
        decimal overalSum = target.ComputeOveralValue();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(totalProduct, 100);
        Assert.AreEqual(totalShipping, 24);
        Assert.AreEqual(overalSum, 124);
    }
}
```

The issue is probably associated with binding Items to Products and Shipping. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please detail what part of the test fails.  Also, it is not clear why/how the cart class test should need to do any mocking of the Repository interfaces.

Comment: @tallseth, I meant that the test runs but fails. Each "assert" statement fails. And You're right: I didn't need to write mocks) But how can I bind these 2 Items to related Products and Shipping??

Comment: Can you add the source for `Item`?

Comment: What do You exactly mean?

Comment: As I see from the code `Item` has property `Product`. Does that property have setter? If no is it virtual then?

Comment: @AlexanderStepaniuk yes, property Product has a setter

Answer (score 2):

The underlying problem here is that details about how you persist your model have leaked in to your model classes, and as a result classes that use your models (like Cart uses Item) have some obligation to understand your persistence layer, which they should not need to do.  This is too much coupling, which is what makes your test hard.

Consider redefining `Item` and adding an `ItemDescription` like so:

```
public class Item
{
   public Product Product {get;set;}
   public Shipping Shipping {get;set;}
}

public class ItemDescription
{
   public int ProductId {get;set;}
   public int ShippingId {get;set;}
}
```

This allows you to test the Cart, and other classes that use your `Item` class quite easily.  I can add an example of that if you need it, but I'm guessing it will be pretty obvious to you.  If you can't change `Item` for some reason, turn this approach upside down and create a `FullyConsitituedItem` class for your `Cart` to use.

The cost here is that you have to create another class that contructs `Item`s from `ItemDescription`s, but you actually would have been doing that anyway, it would just have been done piecemeal all over the place.  Adding `ItemDescription` makes it explicit, which is nicer and more readable.  Certainly more testable.

Comment: I can't change the model. If I would create suggested above Item class and call it for example "ItemHelper" I can't pass it's instance to Add() method as a parameter. You suggest me to create special model for class Cart?? Can You give an example of this approach?

Comment: You can't change Cart either?

Comment: I don't know) Definitely it will affect other parts, so I will need to change them too

Answer (score 0):

You need to directly assign `Product` and `Shipping` for `item1` and `item2` in test method.

See code example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_Compute_Total_Values()
{
    // Arrange 
    var item1 = new Item {
        Product = new Product { Price = 10 },
        Shipping = new Shipping { Cost = 2 }
    };

    var item2 = new Item {
        Product = new Product { Price = 20 },
        Shipping = new Shipping { Cost = 5 }
    };

    var target = new Cart();

    //Act
    target.Add(item1, 2);
    target.Add(item2, 4);

    decimal totalProduct = target.ComputeTotalProductValue();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(totalProduct, 100);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

As it was mentioned in comments there is no need to mock repositories as they are not used in the method which is being tested. This method rather expects that `Product` and `Shipping` are already initialized.
So you need to prepare correct initial data for test manually :).